# Functions defined on Spec of ring $R$ same at every point. Must functions be the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital ring. Suppose $f,g\in R$ such that $f,g$ defines the same function on points of $Spec R$(i.e. $\forall p\in Spec R,f(p)=g(p)$, where $f(p)=\frac{\bar{f}}{1},\bar{f}\in R/p,\frac{\bar{f}}{1}\in Frac(R/p)$.

Q. If $f(p)=g(p)$ for all $p\in Spec R$, should $f=g$? I could not reach such a conclusion. Correct me if I am wrong in the following.

Take any $p\in Spec R$, I have $\frac{\bar{f}}{1}=\frac{\bar{g}}{1}$. Since $R/p$ is integral, I have $\bar{f}=\bar{g}$. So $f-g\in p$. Since $p$ is arbitrary, I must have $f-g\in\cap_{p\in Spec R}p$. Thus $f-g\in Nil(R)$ where $Nil(R)$ is nilradical of $R$. So $(f-g)^m=0$ for some $m\in N$.

I cannot conclude $f=g$ unless $R$ is integral.

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question.  Two elements of $R$ define the same function $$\textrm{Spec}(R) \rightarrow \bigcup\limits_{\mathfrak p \in \textrm{Spec}(R)} R_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$$ if and only if they differ by an element of the nilradical of $R$.  Thus if $\textrm{Nil}(R)$ contains a nonzero element $x$, then $x$ and $0$ define the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the nilradical is the intersection of all primes, you've shown that it's actually the case that $f$ and $g$ agree as functions if and only if $f-g$ is nilpotent.

The answer to your question is yes, with the assumption that $R$ is reduced, and no otherwise.